# Understanding re.search in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to allow users to Enter alphanumerics,underscores and spaces for a name.
I've been using `if not re.search(r'^[\w-]+$', name):` to check if the name has anything other than alphanumerics,underscores and spaces. But here I can just enter one word, not multiple. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing anything obviously wrong.  Your question isn't totally clear either, so I'll try to address a couple of the possible issues.

#### Why is only one word accepted by the regex?

In your regex, you have `\w`, which according to the [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), is just alphanumeric characters and underscore.  What you have *not* included is the space character, so any name with a space (including if it's separating first and last name) will be matched by your regular expression, and therefore turned to `False` by the `not`.  What you should do to check if there are any non-alphanumeric characters/underscores/spaces is the following:

```py
if not re.search(r'^[\w- ]+$', name):
```

Or, if you also for some reason are concerned about newlines (`\n`) or tabs (`\t`) and other kinds of whitespace:

```py
if not re.search(r'^[\w\s- ]+$', name):
```

#### Why can I only check one name at a time?

That's because the regex will only search one string at a time.  If you want to have it check multiple names, you should run the regular expression against each name, in a format like this:

```py
# assuming name_list is a list of name strings
for name in name_list:
    if not re.search(r'^[\w- ]+$', name):
        # do whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex doesn't allow spaces (instead it allows dashes which you didn't mention in your question).

```
if not re.search(r'^[\w ]+$', name):
```

only allows ASCII letters, digits, underscore and spaces (and requires at least one character).

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Your answer is correct, but so is jdotjdot's. And he had posted the anser before you, so It will only be fair if I marked his answer as the right one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a little bit about regular expressions.

I personally started from [Google classes](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) and it was good enough to read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Yeah I guess I will look into it. I still have troubles understanding these expressons